# UIView Background Change Colors with Time

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uibackgroundcolor

In my app, I'm wanting to a section to have an UIView to have colors that change with time. Is this possible and could I do it in an extension? Thank you in advance!!

Like: 
sunrise to 10 - color 
10 to 1 - color 
1 to 4 - color 
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no magical way to achieve this. In some way, you're going to have to do the following:

```
import UIKit

private extension UIColor {

    static func viewBackground(forTime time: Date) -> UIColor {
        let earlyMorningBoundary = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 6, minute: 0, second: 0, of: time)!
        let morningBoundary = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 10, minute: 0, second: 0, of: time)!
        let lunchtimeBoundary = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 13, minute: 0, second: 0, of: time)!
        let afternoonBoundary = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 16, minute: 0, second: 0, of: time)!
        let eveningBoundary = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 19, minute: 0, second: 0, of: time)!
        if time < earlyMorningBoundary {
            return UIColor.earlyMorningColor
        } else if time < morningBoundary {
            return UIColor.morningColor
        } else if time < lunchtimeBoundary {
            return UIColor.lunchtimeColor
        } else if time < afternoonBoundary {
            return UIColor.afternoonColor
        } else {
            return UIColor.eveningColor
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {

    func updateBackgroundForCurrentTime() {
        self.backgroundColor = .viewBackground(forTime: Date())
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    static var earlyMorningColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 60/255, green: 207/255, blue: 228/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    static var morningColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 5.1/255, green: 25.9/255, blue: 87.5/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    static var lunchtimeColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 88.2/255, blue: 45.9/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    static var afternoonColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 64.7/255, blue: 33.7/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    static var eveningColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 49/255, green: 54/255, blue: 57/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

You then need to figure out when you should be calling `updateBackgroundForCurrentTime` to update the background color. Is it when the view is created? When the app is brought into the foreground? Will you queue a local notification to tell you to update? This will all depend on how long you think an app session is likely to last. I would start by updating the color when the app is launched or brought into the foreground and go from there.

Comment: Sorry I have been busy all day. Yes it will be when the view is created, and it will only be instantiated when the app is open.

Comment: Could I add the colors in the if statement?

Comment: How can I make it to where the view keeps updating when the user is in the app?

Comment: Do you definitely _need_ to update it while the app is in the foreground? Will the user have the app in the foreground for long periods? Would it be more sensible to only update the colour when the user either launches the app, or brings it from the background to the foreground?

Comment: Could I just update when the user is using the app, and not in the foreground? Like when the app starts and if they are still in the app when a change of color comes, could I do that?

Comment: your edit can't work, Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIColor.Type' and 'Date'

Comment: @Z.Smouse edit corrected, you're not one for self-service hey?! Yes, you can update if your user is using the app when the colour change comes, but what % of your users will that be? Is it worth the bother? I'd say not. But if you're really set on it, you'll need to schedule a notification/timer to fire when the appropriate time comes.

Comment: I need help doing this, that's why I'm here. I'm wanting to change the color because it'll give more of an UI experience. How can I set a notification?